# Transfer files via Powershell Remoting (like scp in linux)

Tags: powershell, scripting

During the creation of a few powershell-based deployment scripts, I sorely missed an easy way to quickly transfer a file to another server (over the internet) via Powershell Remoting, something like scp for linux.
Fortunately something that can be activated via Powershell Remoting. Did I overlook something?

Comment: Is it over a VPN?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Since it's over the internet, but not through a VPN, how exactly are you connecting with PSRemoting? Are you using PowerShell WebAccess? You will probably need to get the files to an area that is reachable from the internet, from there you might be able to use [Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) to download it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily copy the contents of a file over-the-wire through a PSRemoting session using Invoke-Command and `Set-Content`:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "remotehost.domain.tld" -Credential (Get-Credential) -UseSsl

$FileContents = Get-Content -Path 'C:\path\to\arbitrary.file'
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    param($FilePath,$data)
    Set-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $data
} -ArgumentList "C:\remote\file\path.file",$FileContents
```

Comment: Just a note, this will place the contents of the file into memory, for small files that might not be a big deal, for big files it might be a very real problem.

Answer (score 2):

New in [PowerShell 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395): `Copy-Item` now comes with `-ToSession` and `-FromSession` parameters!

More details and examples here: [Copy To or From a PowerShell Session](http://blogs.technet.com/b/poshchap/archive/2015/10/30/copy-from-one-powershell-session-to-another.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner for you. Works on any version. Transfers binaries if you want.

To put file:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "myserver.somewhere.net" -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {[io.file]::WriteAllBytes($Args[0],$Args[1])} -ArgumentList "c:\remote.file.path",(get-content "c:\local.file.path" -encoding byte -Read 0)
```

To get file(variables not stripped):

```
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes("$localfile",(Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remotehost -Credential $usercred -ScriptBlock {get-content $Args[0] -encoding byte -Read 0} -ArgumentList "$remotefile"))
```